# How to control number of entries that are displayed in YQL RSS feed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rss, yql

I am using YQL to parse an RSS feed on my wordpress website. I have the code working and displaying entries from my RSS feed, but how do I limit the number of entries it displays? Is there a way to display 5 at a time? My code is as follows:

```
    function parseFeed(url, container) {
    // yql query
    var query = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from feednormalizer where url="' + url + '"' ) + '&format=json';

    // send request
    $.getJSON(query, function (data, status, errorThrown) {
        // if successful... *
        if (status === 'success') {
            // log object data in console
            console.log(data);

            // append feed link and title in container
            $(container).append('<a href="' + url + '"><span class="iconicstroke-rss-alt"></span></a>');
            $(container).append('<h1 class="feed">' + data.query.results.rss.channel.title );

            // for each entry... *
            $.each(data.query.results.rss.channel.item, function (key, value) {
                // * create new date object and pass in entry date
                var date = new Date(value.pubDate);

                // * create months array
                var months = new Array(12);
                months[0] = 'January';
                months[1] = 'February';
                months[2] = 'March';
                months[3] = 'April';
                months[4] = 'May';
                months[5] = 'June';
                months[6] = 'July';
                months[7] = 'August';
                months[8] = 'September';
                months[9] = 'October';
                months[10] = 'November';
                months[11] = 'December';

                // * parse month, day and year
                var month = date.getMonth();
                var day = date.getDate();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

                // * build content snippet
                var content = $(value.description).text().substring(0, 340);
                if (value.description.length > content.length ) {
                    content += ' ...';
                }

                // * assign entry variables
                var title = '<h3 class="title"><a href="' + value.link + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></h3>';
                var time = '<p class="time">' + day + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + year + '</p>';
                var snippet = '<p class="snippet">' + content + '</p>';
                var entry = '<div class="entry">' + title + time + snippet + '</div>';

                // * append entire entry in container
                $(container).append(entry);
            });

        // if there's an error... *
        } else if (status === 'error' || status === 'parsererror') {
            // * log error message in console
            console.log(errorThrown);

            // * show error message
            alert('Could not load RSS feed!');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    parseFeed('http://www.vatlive.com/feed/', '#vatrss', '');
});
```